# Centralised Deployment - Ribbon buttons not showing in ribbon

Tags: office-js, office-addins, excel-addins

I am at the stage where I want to deploy my newly developed add-in to my organisation.

I have built and uploaded dist folder to Static Website via Azure Storage.

I have deployed to the admin center using centralised deployment method and is all successful. The add-in appears in the `Get Add-ins > ADMIN MANAGED` section in excel.

When i `add` the add-in, the taskpane opens as expected, however the ribbon buttons do not show on the ribbon...

Manifest Button controls below:

```
<Control xsi:type="Button" id="TaskpaneButton">
  <Label resid="TaskpaneButton.Label"/>
  <Supertip>
    <Title resid="TaskpaneButton.Label"/>
    <Description resid="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip"/>
  </Supertip>
  <Icon>
    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16"/>
    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32"/>
    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80"/>
  </Icon>
  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
    <TaskpaneId>ButtonId1</TaskpaneId>
    <SourceLocation resid="Taskpane.Url"/>
  </Action>
</Control>

<Control xsi:type="Button" id="AutoFillButton">
  <Label resid="AutoFillButton.Label"/>
  <Supertip>
    <Title resid="AutoFillButton.Label"/>
    <Description resid="AutoFillButton.Tooltip"/>
  </Supertip>
  <Icon>
    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16"/>
    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32"/>
    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80"/>
  </Icon>
  <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
    <FunctionName>action</FunctionName>
  </Action>
  <Enabled>true</Enabled>
</Control>

<Control xsi:type="Button" id="AddNewBAButton">
  <Label resid="AddNewBAButton.Label"/>
  <Supertip>
    <Title resid="AddNewBAButton.Label"/>
    <Description resid="AddNewBAButton.Tooltip"/>
  </Supertip>
  <Icon>
    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16"/>
    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32"/>
    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80"/>
  </Icon>
  <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
    <FunctionName>action3</FunctionName>
  </Action>
  <Enabled>true</Enabled>
</Control>
```

I assumed it may be to do with the new logo that I tried to add to the add-in, so I removed and went back to the original `logo` template provided when creating add-in with Yeoman, however the buttons still do not show.

The taskpane 'onChange' functions still work while the add-in is running so i assume all the files are online and available...

I am stumped with this does anyone know whats wrong? Help!

Comment: I've moved from office computer onto laptop and the add-in is now working as intended. Relief!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with the same issue, the cause of the issue was deploying the add-in via the SharePoint app catalog and also Centralized Deployment.

Once i removed the address Catalog URL from `File > Options > Trust Center > Trust Center Settings > Trusted Add-in Catalogs` in excel, the add-in successfully loaded.